# Cannot connect heroku to mongolabs database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I am a new dev and I have no idea what I am doing in regards to deploying my app. Locally, I can run it perfectly. I have setup a heroku account and a mongolabs account. My app.js file starts my app, and I have that set properly in heroku and when I do the heroku logs it shows that is attemps to start it but crashes when it cant find mongodb. I could have my code completely wrong, I am lost and don't know where to find the answer. I have been looking for hours. The username and password is swapped below but I use the correct credentials when trying to send the file.

My app.js file is:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var reddit = require('./routes/reddit');
var enter = require('./routes/enter');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var update = require('./routes/update');
var message = require('./routes/message');
var register = require('./routes/register');
var login = require('./routes/login');
var rate = require('./routes/rate');
var credentials = require ('./routes/request-credentials');
var uri = 'mongodb://removed:removed@ds045734.mongolab.com:45734/bubsta';
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db){
    if(err) throw err;
});

app.use('/', reddit);
app.use('/user', user);
app.use('/enter', enter);
app.use('/update', update);
app.use('/login', login);
app.use('/message', message);
app.use('/register', register);
app.use('/rate', rate);
app.use('/credentials', credentials);
app.use(express.static('public/dist'));
app.use(express.static('public/js'));
app.use(express.static('public/dist/images'));
app.use(express.static('bower_components'));

app.listen(1337);
console.log('Started on server 1337');
```

the file that creates the schema and connects is as follows. I have commented out the old code that works locally, but am including it just so you see that I had previously connected and why I assume I am supposed to put my new code here.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Users/mike/project-two/users');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://removed:removed@ds045734.mongolab.com:45734/bubsta');

var User = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, index: { unique: true }},
    password: String,
    email: String,
    positive: Number,
    negative: Number,
    points: Number,
    title: String,
    sessions: Number,
    roomFull: Boolean
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', User);
```

if someone could help me write the correct code, or even point me in the right direction with documentation that explains how to set up a file so that I can use mongolabs with heroku I would be very appreciative.

Comment: see [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab) for heroku's tutorial. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it. I needed to use:

```
var mongoUri = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI

mongo.connect(mongoUri, function(err, db){
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log('success');
    };
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 1337);
```

then for my mongoose connection I needed:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://heroku_somecodeherebutnotthisonec@ds048704.mongolab.com:48704/heroku_3rjmclqw');
```